# Does anyone knows any SSH client with reconnect and capable to get password from file?

Tags: ssh, passwords, reconnect

I need a ssh client capable to reconnect if connection breaks, and, on reconnection, to get password from a file or web address.

Thank You.

Comment: You cannot get a ready made program for EVERYTHING you need to get done. Take effort, write a script...

Comment: could you help me a little bit? how am I supposed to implement that script to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking around, there does exist [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/).

Rely on autossh to reconnect a broken connections (if everything else is right).

Then you may fetch files or execute any other commands.

---

Alternatively, you can run a script to loop and check for the port, some like [this](http://scrolls.mafgani.net/2006/03/ssh-automatic-reconnect-on-timeout/).

---

Or you may simply [use scp](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/xfer/scp.html) to fetch the required file.